# Effective creation of Subclasses which have four (2 x 2) options

Tags: matlab, class, oop, subclass

I am very new to OOP in Matlab. Let's say I have a super class with one property, X. Next I want to define subclasses that has properties V, A, and B, where V is some manipulation of X, with four options:

```
 V = A1*X - B1;
 V = A1*X - B2;
 V = A2*X - B1;
 V = A2*X - B2;
```

In the actual code the options are something completely different, and it takes quite some time to calculate V, so once it is calculated I definitely want to store it. (In fact my options for A and B are actually discrete choices, so there are really just four possible combinations).

So what I did is: I created a subclass, VClass, with properties A, B, V (and X).

The SuperClass has methods:

```
function obj = SuperClass(X)

     obj.XX = XX;
end

function add_V(obj,A,B)
     if A == A1 && B == B1;
         obj.A1B1 = VClass();
         obj.A1B1.init_V(X,A,B);
     elseif A == A2 && B == B1; 
         obj.A2B1 = VClass();
         obj.A2B1.init_V(X,A,B);

     et cetera...
end
```

The VClass has method:

```
  function init_V(obj,X,A,B)

         obj.V = A*X - B;
         obj.A = A;
         obj.B = B;
         obj.X = X;
  end
```

The thing that I don't like is that I created subclasses with names A1B1, A1B2, A2B1, and A2B2, so in every method I repeat a lot of code. I suppose I could use 'eval' with creation of a name for the subclass:

```
if A == A1 && B == B1;
     name = 'A1B1';
 .....
```

and in combination with:

```
eval(['obj.',name,' = VClass();']);
eval(['obj.',name,'.init_V(X,A,B);']);
```

But I am not too happy about that either, since it makes the code difficult to read.

Does anybody have another suggestion? (and any other comments of course also very welcome, since I just started with OOP)

Comment: Don't ever do `eval(['obj.',name,' = VClass();']);`. It's hard to read, bad for the interpreter, and potentially dangerous. Instead do `obj.(name) = VClass();`.

Comment: Regarding your question: It looks like you are trying to add the subclass as a property of the superclass. This is not how you should be using subclasses. You should directly instantiate an object of the subclass, it will automatically contain its superclass. Thus, your client code does `obj = VClass(X,A,B)`, the the constructor to `VClass` computes `V` from the parameters. `SuperClass` should not have a method `add_V`. `SuperClass` does not know about `A` and `B`, so it should not try to compute with those. Or, let `SuperClass` know about those, and don't use inheritance at all (no `VClass`).

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for the feedback! Do I understand it correctly that you would store the four options into one class? So each option is a different property (properties Va1b1, Va1b2, et cetera). I mean I would prefer to use one input argument (a class containing the four options) into a function.

Comment: Are all of these `Vxxx` scalar values? It seems like this would be simplified if you just stored the result in a matrix `obj.V = [Va1b1, Va1b2; Va2b1, Va2b2]` (without needing the variable names in the matrix to be properties of your objects).

Comment: It looks to me that you are not computing the four options, only one. Why do you need four different names if you’re storing only one of them?